# Read and Sort a file to array Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm attempting to write a program that would read a file "data.txt" which has an undefined amount of numbers in random order, separated by line. It would add these numbers into an array and print out the numbers in one line, each separated by a comma "x, x1". Then on the next line it would print out (in the same format) the list of numbers which has been sorted from smallest to largest size.

Data type is integer.

Currently, I have coded for 3 methods which would allow the array to be sorted (I think they have no error).

I've created another method to read the file and am using a two-step process - once to figure out the number of lines in the file (I ask that this two-step process remain). This method seems to have trouble returning the "lineCount" and apparently I need to make this variable an array (which I find bizarre). How can I fix this code?

You may notice that my method for printing is empty; I have not figured out a way to print the array so that each number is separated by a comma. How do I code for this?

My code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SortAndSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile2Array();
        printArray();
        selectionSort();
        printArray();
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] a) {

    }

    public static void selectionSort(int[] a) {
        int minI = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < a.length - 1; ++k) {
            minI = findMinIdx(a, k); // findMinIdx at k-th
            swapElement(a, k, minI);// swapElement at k-th
        }
    }

    public static int findMinIdx(int[] a, int k) {
        int minIdx = k;
        for (int i = k + 1; i < a.length; ++i)
            if (a[i] < a[minIdx])
                minIdx = i;

        return minIdx;
    }

    public static void swapElement(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static int[] readFile2Array(String fileName) {

            File dat = new File("data.txt"); 
            int lineCount = 0; 
            int[] a = new int[lineCount];
            int i;

          try{ Scanner sc = new Scanner(dat);

          while (sc.hasNextLine()){ //first read to count -> int lineCount;
          lineCount++; 
          return lineCount; //I have trouble with this line
          }

          while (sc.hasNextLine()){ //second read to array -> hasNext(),
             a[i] = sc.nextInt();

          return a; 
          } 
          } 
          catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
              System.out.println("File cannot be opened");
              e.printStackTrace();
          } 

    }


      public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int val){ 
          int minIdx, maxIdx, index = -1; 
          while(){ int middleIdx = (minIdx + maxIdx)/2; 
          if( arr[???] ==val){ 
              index = middleIdx; 
              break } // update minIdx, maxIdx //if smaller then cut right, if larger then cut left 
          }

      return index; }

}
```

The last method in the program would attempt to locate the element number of a user inputted number by using this (pseudo)code:

```
1.  Let ‭min = 0‬ and ‭max = n-1‬ (where n is the array’s length)‬‬‬‬
2.  If ‭max < min‬, then stop: ‭target‬ is not present in ‭array‬. return ‭false‬.‬‬‬‬‬‬‬‬
3.  Compute ‭guess‬ as the average of ‭max‬ and ‭min‬, rounded down (so that it is an integer).‬‬‬‬‬‬
4.  If ‭array[guess]‬ equals ‭target‬, then stop. You found it! Return ‭guess‬.‬‬‬‬‬‬
5.  If the guess was too low, that is, ‭array[guess] < target‬, then set ‭min = guess + 1‬.‬‬‬‬
6.  Otherwise, the guess was too high. Set ‭max = guess - 1‬.‬‬
7.  Go back to step 2.
```

How would I code for this?

I would really appreciate any help in any area of this program!

Comment: You've described your program, but you didn't ask any actual questions.

Comment: Thanks, I added three questions in the three parts I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with VGR that you haven't actually asked a question, but by reading your code I guess that you were describing what you wanted to achieve...

There are some flaws in your readFile2Array-method, which might solve the problem:

1)

```
int lineCount = 0; 
int[] a = new int[lineCount]; //The size of a will always be 0, so you can't add anything to it, even though you are trying to do this later. Consider using a List instead, as the size of the list can increase dynamically.
```

2)

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()){ //first read to count -> int lineCount;
    lineCount++; 
    return lineCount; //I have trouble with this line
}
//The problem is the return type: You method signature states that you will return int[], but here you are trying to return an int.
//It will also just increase lineCount once and try to return this.
```

3)

```
//Your scanning will be at the 2nd line because of 2) and not going through the entire file again. To do this you need to create a new instance of Scanner. And the int[] a has a size of 0 at this point. 
while (sc.hasNextLine()){ //second read to array -> hasNext(),
    a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    return a; 
}
```

So in order to solve this you should refactor your code to something like:

```
public static List<Integer> readFile2Array(String fileName) {
    File dat = new File("data.txt"); 
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();

    try{ Scanner sc = new Scanner(dat);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){ 
            a.add(sc.nextInt());
        } 

        sc.close(); //Always remember to close, when done :) 
        System.out.println("Added " + a.size() + " lines to the list.");
        return a; 

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("File cannot be opened");
        e.printStackTrace();

        return new ArrayList<>();
    } 
}
```

What I changed:

- removed the lineCount as this is implicit stored in the size of the list called a.
- Changed the int[] a to a List as this always will allow adding elements by increasing its size when needed.
- Removed i as was never used, only initialized.
- Removed the first while-loop as we don't need to know the amount of lines that is going to be added.
- Added a return-statement in the catch-closure. We need to return something (even an empty array or maybe the not-yet-finished array)

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the first part of the code:

readFile2Array method:

```
 public static int[] readFile2Array(String fileName) {
        try {
            int lineCount = 0;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNext()) { // first read to count -> int lineCount;
                lineCount++; // second read to array -> hasNext(),
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            sc.close();

            sc = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            int[] x = new int[lineCount];
            int n = 0;
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                x[n] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                n++;
            }
            sc.close();
            return x;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File cannot be opened");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Print array separated by comma:

```
public static void printArray(int[] a) {
        try {
            int lineCount = 0;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                lineCount++;
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            sc.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
            if (i < lineCount-1) System.out.print(", ");
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File cannot be opened");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Last method is still a mystery to me though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you got that part working. :)

To print out the array, it will be best to use whatever data you have of the array. By calling a.length, you don't have to count the number of lines from the input again, which you are not guaranteed are still the same if the input has changed in the mean time.

So this piece of code should do the trick:

```
public static void printArray(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        if (i < a.length-1) System.out.print(", ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```